# Error in the book Applied Machine Learning Using mlr3 in R example

Tags: r, mlr3

I recently began exploring mlr3 through the book "Applied Machine Learning Using mlr3 in R". However, I'm currently stuck on the second example and unable to proceed further. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 as my operating system and R version 4.3.2.

```
library(mlr3verse)
tasks = tsks(c("breast_cancer", "sonar"))
glrn_rf_tuned = as_learner(ppl("robustify") %>>% auto_tuner(
  tnr("grid_search", resolution = 5),
  lrn("classif.ranger", num.trees = to_tune(200, 500)),
  rsmp("holdout")
))
glrn_rf_tuned$id = "RF"
glrn_stack = as_learner(ppl("robustify") %>>% ppl("stacking", lrns(c("classif.rpart", "classif.kknn")), lrn("classif.log_reg")))
```

and I get this error:

> Error in gunion(list(g1, g2), in_place = c(TRUE, TRUE)) :
> Assertion on 'ids of pipe operators of graphs' failed: Must have unique names, but element 18 is duplicated.

Are you encountering the same error? Could the issue be with my system configuration, or is there an error in the example itself?

Comment: Please don't cross post. The issue in the repository is the right place for this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a bug report and OP already opened an issue about this in the appropriate repository.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It can often be challenging to discern whether the issue I'm experiencing is due to a mistake on my part or if it's a bug.